# jquery toggle other checkbox if a user clicks on one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two checkboxes "obsolete" and "pending". 
If a user clicks on one of the two checkboxes, then the other checkbox should be disabled.
If the user unselect one checkbox then both of the checkboxes should be selectable.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("input.obsolete").click(toggle_checkbox());
      $("input.pending").click(toggle_checkbox());
    });
    
    function toggle_checkbox() {
      if($('input.obsolete').checked) {
        $("input.pending").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $("input.pending").removeAttr("disabled");
      };
    
      if($('input.pending').checked) {
        $("input.obsolete").attr("disabled", true);
      }  else {
        $("input.obsolete").removeAttr("disabled");
      };
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
      obsolete
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
      pending 
    </div>
```

But I still can click on both checkboxes. What am I missing?

Comment: `#ID` you can only use once. And what you want to use is `radio-buttons`.

Comment: use radio buttons maybe?

Comment: You should be using radio buttons for this... also, never use `attrr()` or `removeAttr()` for boolean attributes and properties. Use `prop()` instead.

Comment: radio buttons are once clicked not deselectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
  obsolete
  <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
  pending 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing `$('input.pending').checked` in jQuery, instead use `$('input.pending').is(":checked")`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.obsolete").click(toggle_checkbox);
  $("input.pending").click(toggle_checkbox);
});

function toggle_checkbox() {
    $("input.pending").attr("disabled", $('input.obsolete').is(":checked"));

    $("input.obsolete").attr("disabled", $('input.pending').is(":checked"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" class="obsolete" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
  obsolete
  <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" class="pending" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
  pending 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("input.obsolete").click(toggle_checkbox);
      $("input.pending").click(toggle_checkbox);
    });
    
    function toggle_checkbox() {
      if($('input.obsolete').prop('checked')) {
        $("input.pending").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $("input.pending").removeAttr("disabled");
      };
    
      if($('input.pending').prop('checked')) {
        $("input.obsolete").attr("disabled", true);
      }  else {
        $("input.obsolete").removeAttr("disabled");
      };
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent" class="obsolete"> 
      obsolete
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent" class="pending"> 
      pending 
    </div>
```

To change your code to work, Please change like below.

1. add class name to checkbox like below

> ```
> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]"
>  id="job_invoice_sent" class="obsolete"> obsolete 
>
> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]"
>  id="job_invoice_sent" class="pending">pending
> ```

2. Change some code.

   **FROM**

> $("input.obsolete").click(toggle_checkbox());
>
> $("input.pending").click(toggle_checkbox());

**TO**

> $("input.obsolete").click(toggle_checkbox);
>
> $("input.pending").click(toggle_checkbox);

3. change if statement like below

> if($('input.obsolete').prop('checked')) {
>
> // some code
>
> }

~~~~~~~~~~

> BUT I SUGGEST YOU TO USE "RADIO" NOT THE CHECKBOX FOR LIKE THIS REASON!!

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code and assign an event handler for all `input:checkbox` elements instead of making it separately.

Here an simple snippet by making use of jQueries `not()` function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
      $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
      obsolete
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
      pending 
    </div>
```

---

## NOTE:

It would be easier in your case to use `radio`-inputs instead of dealing with checkboxes. Simply assign all `radio`-inputs the same `name` attribute and you get your desired behaviour

#### DEMO:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input type="radio" value="pending" name="example">pending
      <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input type="radio" value="obsolete" name="example">obsolete
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add one `className` in your all checkbox input type and use below concept to implement

```js
$('input[class^="class"]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.is(".className")) {
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
           
            $(".className").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
        } 
        else{
        
            $(".className").not($this).prop({ disabled: false, checked: false });
        
        }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" class="className" value="1" name="abcd" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
  obsolete
  <input name="job[invoice_sent]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" class="className" value="1" name="job[invoice_sent]" id="job_invoice_sent"> 
  pending 
</div>
```